# Idiomatic Hello world (and nothing more than Hello world)

Tags: r

What is the idiomatic way to print a literal string to the output?  For example, if I want to print `Hello world` to the output...

not `[1] "Hello world"`,

not `[1] Hello world`,

... but `Hello world`, like this:

```
> rscript hello.r
Hello world
```

I've seen `cat` used for this purpose, but I'm not sure if this is idiomatic.  I've also seen `print(x, quote=FALSE)`, but it is not obvious how to go about removing the `[1]` decoration.

Comment: check out ?message

Comment: writeLines is usually my goto, I can include special characters (like \n) which is very handy

Comment: Why do you care what's "idiomatic"? Use the solution that's suitable for your real problem.